# How to compare prev props and current props with react hooks in right way?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to get previous props and current props which come from component and then I need to check them. I made like in React documentation but all the time I have the same values for current and previous props. I can't find where I wrote bad code.

Hook to find previous props

```
export default function usePrevious(index: number) {
  const ref = useRef<any>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = index;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Hook to show previous and current hook

```
export const useShowPrevIndex = (index: number) => {
  const prevCount = usePrevious(index);
  console.log(prevCount, index); // they are the same
};
```

This how I use it in component

```
useShowPrevIndex(index);
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. See this working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-compare-prev-props-and-current-props-with-react-hooks-in-right-way-9p8sl

Comment: I get index in component like props and this variant didn't work. I already try it. Show prev and current are the same

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can, try also creating a *running* codesandbox of your own that reproduces this issue.